# Popup edit window doesn't appear in filterable mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Popup window doesn't appear if there is a filter on a grid column.

I've added filterable: true in editing-popup.html example file and "Add New Record" doesn't show popup window anymore. (But the new row is still added without validation)

It looks like a bug.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: true,
    height: 430,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
        { field:"ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
        { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "100px" },
        { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "100px" },
        { field: "Discontinued", width: "100px" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "160px" }],
    editable: "popup"
});
```

Comment: can you share the code ?

Comment: It is one of the example files in the download archive: editing-popup.html. I just added the "filterable: true".

Comment: I think its already mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923285/kendo-toolbar-addnew-button-doesnt-work-when-the-grid-is-filtered?rq=1

Comment: i dont see any problem can you check the fiddle that i created http://jsfiddle.net/u3N4h/

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, grid should "filterable: true" AND you should filter the rows, then it doesn't work. It is same in your example too.

Comment: as a work around you can write a function to custom insert